# Wait for Even type Activity in a waterfallstep dialog (bot framework 4.0)

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

It's possible to wait and receive an Event type activity in a waterfall step dialog. I use directline 3.0 and inside a dialog  flow I send an event from the bot to the client. After i would like to send an event from the client to the bot as an answer to previous send. If i use prompt await dc.Prompt("waitEvent",activity) where waitEvent is a textprompt and i answer with a message it works fine but I would like to answer to an event with an event. I was thinking that i could write a custom prompt but i didn't find documentation and obviously I could manage the conversation flow but I prefer use Dialogs where possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ActivityPrompt` abstract class](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/efae0195e737d8d2cbd36f5910d7e848a5355d92/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/ActivityPrompt.cs) to build an "EventActivityPrompt" class.

There aren't any BotFramework samples of this usage yet, but there are [new tests](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/tests/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Tests/ActivityPromptTests.cs#L60-L100) written by the BotFramework team that you can use as an example.

To create your own EventActivityPrompt, you just need to implement the ActivityPrompt like so:

```
public class EventActivityPrompt : ActivityPrompt
{
    public EventActivityPrompt(string dialogId, PromptValidator<Activity> validator)
        : base(dialogId, validator)
    {
    }
}
```

The core difference between an ActivityPrompt and other Prompts (besides its `abstract` status) is that ActivityPrompts require a `PromptValidator<Activity>`, in order to validate the user input.

The next step is to create your validator. Here is the example:

```
async Task<bool> _validator(PromptValidatorContext<Activity> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var activity = promptContext.Recognized.Value;
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Event)
        {
            if ((int)activity.Value == 2)
            {
                promptContext.Recognized.Value = MessageFactory.Text(activity.Value.ToString());
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await promptContext.Context.SendActivityAsync("Please send an 'event'-type Activity with a value of 2.");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Corina, i was in trouble as i used a pre release sdk where the Prompt Activity Abstract class wasn't exposed. Thanks a lot